# Tabstrip of tablayout in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, android-tabstrip

How to customize tabstrip of tablayout especially if we want fixed and user defined width of tabstrip irrespective to tab?
Particular, we want tabstrip to the bottom center of each tab but it should not has width more than that tab, neither it should have width the same of that tab but, the tabstrip must have small width than that of tab and if possible, user should be able to define or customize the width of tabstrip. 
Is there any way by which we can customize tabstrip at once and use it for our all tablayout?

Comment: You can only use `PagerTabStrip` or `TabLayout`.

Comment: @KeLiuyue Thank you for comment, but how is it possible with tablayout?

Comment: You can have a try.We also used `ViewPager and PagerTabStrip` or `ViewPager and TabLayout`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I will try with PagerTabStrip!

Comment: Ok.If you have problems，you can ask me.

Comment: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout
Working!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

For those who has same kind of requirements!